# numeric or value error: raw variable length too long ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_RAW"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I  am facing **raw variable length too long** issue when select the BLOB(Stored JSON string) filed value from the table.

**Query:**

```
  select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(TRANSACTION_DATA)) from PS_ISA_INB_PAYLOAD_LOG;
```

This is my SP i have used to insert the JSON object into BLOB Field:

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE SDIX_TICK_LOG 
    (
      ORGANIZATIONNAME IN VARCHAR2 
    , TRANSACTION_TYPE IN VARCHAR2 
    , TRANSACTION_DATA IN BLOB 
    , TRANSACTION_STATUS IN VARCHAR2 
    ) AS 
     l_r   RAW(32767);

      l_blob        blob;
      l_clob        clob :='"ItemMasterTransfer":[{"ORACLE_UNIQUE_REC_ID":"123assd4434","CUSTOMER_ID":"PMC","ORGANIZATION_CODE":"BMftrdsM","ITEM":"696738","INVENTORY_ITEM_ID":"0000000000000000000000000000546","ORGANIZATION_ID":" ","SUBINVENTORY_CODE":"000000000000000000","LOCATOR_ID":" ","ISA_MATERIAL_GROUP":" ","TAX_GROUP":" ","CATEGORY_ID":"1956","NOUN":" ","MODIFIER":" ","MANUFACTURER_ID":" ","MFG_ITEM_ID":" ","UNIT_OF_MEASURE":"BOX","ITEM_TYPE":"P","STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG":"Y","INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE":"A","LIST_PRICE_PER_UNIT":"0","FULL_LEAD_TIME":"0","MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY":"10","MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY":"10","SAFETY_LEVEL":"0","REPLENISH_TO_ORDER_FLAG":"N","UTILIZ_CD":"","CURRENCY_CD":"USD","DESCRIPTION":"","ATTRIBUTE1":" ","ATTRIBUTE2":" ","ATTRIBUTE3":" ","ATTRIBUTE4":" ","ATTRIBUTE5":" ","ATTRIBUTE6":" ","ATTRIBUTE7":" ","ATTRIBUTE8":" ","ATTRIBUTE9":" ","ATTRIBUTE10":" ","TRANSACTION_STATUS":" ","TRANS_STATUS_DESCRIPTION":" "},{"ORACLE_UNIQUE_REC_ID":"123assd4434","CUSTOMER_ID":"PMC","ORGANIZATION_CODE":"BMftrdsM","ITEM":"696738","INVENTORY_ITEM_ID":"0000000000000000000000000000546","ORGANIZATION_ID":" ","SUBINVENTORY_CODE":"000000000000000000","LOCATOR_ID":" ","ISA_MATERIAL_GROUP":" ","TAX_GROUP":" ","CATEGORY_ID":"1956","NOUN":" ","MODIFIER":" ","MANUFACTURER_ID":" ","MFG_ITEM_ID":" ","UNIT_OF_MEASURE":"BOX","ITEM_TYPE":"P","STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG":"Y","INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE":"A","LIST_PRICE_PER_UNIT":"0","FULL_LEAD_TIME":"0","MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY":"10","MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY":"10","SAFETY_LEVEL":"0","REPLENISH_TO_ORDER_FLAG":"N","UTILIZ_CD":"","CURRENCY_CD":"USD","DESCRIPTION":"","ATTRIBUTE1":" ","ATTRIBUTE2":" ","ATTRIBUTE3":" ","ATTRIBUTE4":" ","ATTRIBUTE5":" ","ATTRIBUTE6":" ","ATTRIBUTE7":" ","ATTRIBUTE8":" ","ATTRIBUTE9":" ","ATTRIBUTE10":" ","TRANSACTION_STATUS":" ","TRANS_STATUS_DESCRIPTION":" "},{"ORACLE_UNIQUE_REC_ID":"123assd4434","CUSTOMER_ID":"PMC","ORGANIZATION_CODE":"BMftrdsM","ITEM":"696738","INVENTORY_ITEM_ID":"0000000000000000000000000000546","ORGANIZATION_ID":" ","SUBINVENTORY_CODE":"000000000000000000","LOCATOR_ID":" ","ISA_MATERIAL_GROUP":" ","TAX_GROUP":" ","CATEGORY_ID":"1956","NOUN":" ","MODIFIER":" ","MANUFACTURER_ID":" ","MFG_ITEM_ID":" ","UNIT_OF_MEASURE":"BOX","ITEM_TYPE":"P","STOCK_ENABLED_FLAG":"Y","INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE":"A","LIST_PRICE_PER_UNIT":"0","FULL_LEAD_TIME":"0","MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY":"10","MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY":"10","SAFETY_LEVEL":"0","REPLENISH_TO_ORDER_FLAG":"N","UTILIZ_CD":"","CURRENCY_CD":"USD","DESCRIPTION":"","ATTRIBUTE1":" ","ATTRIBUTE2":" ","ATTRIBUTE3":" ","ATTRIBUTE4":" ","ATTRIBUTE5":" ","ATTRIBUTE6":" ","ATTRIBUTE7":" ","ATTRIBUTE8":" ","ATTRIBUTE9":" ","ATTRIBUTE10":" ","TRANSACTION_STATUS":" ","TRANS_STATUS_DESCRIPTION":" "}],"Organization":"PMC Biogenix","SharedSecret":"sTc1QowIu5Iy1Qt8iilnmQ==","TimeStamp":"09/28/2018 00:19:21","RowsSent":"1"}';
      l_amt         integer := dbms_lob.lobmaxsize;
      l_dest_offset integer := 1;
      l_src_offset  integer := 1;
      l_csid        integer := dbms_lob.default_csid;
      l_ctx         integer := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
      l_warn        integer;

    BEGIN

     dbms_lob.createTemporary( l_blob, false );
      dbms_lob.convertToBlob( l_blob,
                              l_clob,
                              l_amt,
                              l_dest_offset,
                              l_src_offset,
                              l_csid,
                              l_ctx,
                              l_warn );

    INSERT INTO PS_ISA_INB_PAYLOAD_LOG Values(ORGANIZATIONNAME,TRANSACTION_TYPE,l_blob,SYSDATE,TRANSACTION_STATUS); 
END SDIX_TICK_LOG;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies here: `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()`

`DBMS_LOB` is using `VARCHAR2` internally, and `VARCHAR2` has limit of **2000** chars. Your blob has the size of **2829** chars, therefore it is too long to be processed by `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR()` at once.

You can test this by these commands:

Take only first **2000** chars from BLOB:

```
 select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(TRANSACTION_DATA), 2000, 1) from PS_ISA_INB_PAYLOAD_LOG;
```

OK.

Take **2001** chars from BLOB:

```
select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(TRANSACTION_DATA, 2001, 1)) from PS_ISA_INB_PAYLOAD_LOG;
```

> Error report -
>   SQL Error:
>
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> 06502.00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"

Comment: Is that possible to select entire BLOB Field value?

Comment: utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(TRANSACTION_DATA, 2000, 1)) worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Is that possible to select entire BLOB Field value?
```

Basically, no. You'll need a PL/SQL function similar to the one you've already described, except this time, it will go BLOB-to-CLOB. You can call that from SQL, if it returns a CLOB or a VARCHAR2(4000).

As a side note, I question why you're taking JSON, which is character data, and storing it as a BLOB, then wanting to get character data back. Why not just store it as a CLOB in the first place?