# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I am facing `raw variable length too long issue` when I select the BLOB tried some answer from `stackoverflow` but not helping.

Is there any way to get all data from `BLOB` field? **I can adjust if we get data in two or more columns.**

Here is my query -

```
SELECT ID,
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(NOTE_VALUE))
FROM XYZ t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC t2 ON 
t1.SPEC_ID = T2.SPEC_ID
```

Here is Error -

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

**Tried below answer but not working**

[numeric or value error: raw variable length too long ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_RAW"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719281/numeric-or-value-error-raw-variable-length-too-long-ora-06512-at-sys-utl-raw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue by using below query -

```
SELECT ID,
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(NOTE_VALUE, 2000, 1)) as First_Part,
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(NOTE_VALUE, 4000, 2001)) as Second_Part,
utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(NOTE_VALUE, 6000, 4001)) as third_Part,
FROM XYZ t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC t2 ON 
t1.SPEC_ID = T2.SPEC_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, the maximum length for VARCHAR2 is 4000 bytes (unless your database has modified [MAX_STRING_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321)). The maximum length for RAW is 2000 bytes (again if MAX_STRING_SIZE hasn't been changed).

Since you are not specifying a length when calling `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`, it is defaulting to 32767. If you shorten the length to 2000, you should not get an error.

```sql
SELECT ID, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (NOTE_VALUE, 2000))
  FROM XYZ t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC t2 ON t1.SPEC_ID = T2.SPEC_ID
```

Another option is that instead of going from BLOB -> RAW -> VARCHAR2, you could try going from BLOB -> CLOB -> VARCHAR2 so that you can get 4000 characters instead of 2000 characters

```sql
SELECT ID, SUBSTR (TO_CLOB (NOTE_VALUE), 1, 4000)
  FROM XYZ t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC t2 ON t1.SPEC_ID = T2.SPEC_ID;
```

Comment: showing same error for your query as well :(

Comment: Just updated answer. Maximum length for a RAW is 2000 bytes. Try the queries now and see if they work for you.

Comment: not working...:( facing `ORA-22994: source offset is beyond the end of the source LOB` Error.

Comment: for which query? Have you tried both? are there any `NOTE_VALUE` values that are empty?

Comment: for 2nd query... Yes there are some records with `null` or `empty` value